# special characters problem after cleaning stop-words

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, stop-words

I am new to text analysis with Python and struggling to clean my data from special characters.

I have survey data where one of the columns has comments. I want to analyse these comments and find the most frequent words. I try to exclude the stop words by using pandas.Series.str.replace.

Here is my code:

```py
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# get the relevant column from the dataset:
df_comments = df.iloc[:,[-3]].dropna()

#clean it from stop words
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stop_words))
df['comment_without_stopwords'] = df["comment"].str.replace(pat, '')
df['comment_without_stopwords'] = df['comment_without_stopwords'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')

# get the most frequent 20 words:
result = df['comment_without_stopwords'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts(normalize=True, ascending = False).head(20)
```

But as a result I get the following characters: `.`, and `-` in my top list as can be seen below. How can I get rid of them?

```py
staff        0.015001
need         0.009265
work         0.007942
-            0.007059
action       0.006618
project      0.005074
contract     0.005074
.            0.004853
field        0.004412
support      0.004412
employees    0.004191
projects     0.004191
HR           0.003971
time         0.003971
HQ           0.003971
needs        0.003750
field        0.003530
training     0.003530
capacity     0.003530
good         0.003530
dtype: float64
```

Comment: When you remove the stop words, you could remove the special characters. I'd think it should be as simple as adding them to your stop list

Comment: Before removing stopwords, remove any non alphanumeric characters with regex, you can find many examples on stackoverflow